# Xmpp4r Google Talk Unable To Set Presence

Tags: ruby, gmail, google-talk, xmpp4r

I want to be able to set my presence (ie status and availability) for my google talk from a ruby script. I can't seem to be able to make it work using xmpp4r. I think it might either be that google talk doesn't set the presence through this xml protocol anymore (that being the presence tag), and/or I need to use the pubsub library included with xmpp4r. Much help is highly appreciated! My code so far:

```
class Simplified
  require 'xmpp4r'
  include Jabber

  def initialize(usr, pwd, host, rsrc='', port=5222)
    @usr = usr
    @pwd = pwd
    @host = host
    @rsrc = rsrc
    @port = port

    @cl = Client.new(JID.new("#{@usr}/#{@rsrc}"))
    @cl.connect(host, port)
    @cl.auth(pwd)
  end

  # :chat, nil, :dnd, :away, :xa, :unavailable, :error
  def status(presence, msg)
    @presence = presence
    @stat_msg = msg
    stat_msg = Presence.new.set_show(:chat)
    # stat_msg = Presence.new(@presence, @status_message, 24)
    send stat_msg
  end

  def send(msg)
    @cl.send(msg)
  end
end

usr = 'joeuser@gmail.com'
pwd = 'password'
host = 'talk.google.com'
rsrc = 'test'

me = Simplified.new(usr, pwd, host, rsrc)
me.status(:dnd,'new status')
```

Comment: did you found out how to cope with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the regular xmpp4r library:

Your client has to send a "presence" stanza:

```
@cl.send(Jabber::Presence.new.set_type(':available'))
```